# Voice generating program for my game

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice

I created an android game using gl. I want to create a story mode for the game. In the story mode obviously there is a story.. I don't want to use my voice to narrate the story and the characters' voices and I don't want to get someone speak instead. Is there any program that i can generate voices and use Text-To-Speech or something like that? I don't want the robot voice that people usually use for videos and stuff. I want to actually create the voice and write text that it will read and also to record it. Is there something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does have a built-in TTS engine:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

However, the results probably won't be up to scratch for narration -- machine TTS is still kind of weak, especially if you're trying to convey any emotion. It isn't likely to work as  a substitute for real voice actors.

Comment: what about hatsuna miku? they generated voices using a software that they made, it is in Japanese so i have no idea how to use the program. any ideas? 

btw: hatsuna miku - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatsune_Miku#Sales

Comment: Vocaloid has had a lot more time spent on it than the Android TTS engine. `:)` Even at that, I suspect you still have to do a bunch of tweaking for intonation.

Comment: Isn't there any software that i can record for example part of my voice or someone else's and use it to read text? or play with it so it would say certain words?

Comment: Nothing generally available that I'm aware of. Realistic voices are *hard*.